# scrapy / python 3.5 : targeting and filtering

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, python-3.5

i want to extract the following field : movie's,director's,actors' name
on the page [allocine.fr](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=29007.html)

This will help me to make my template for further scraps.

Here is my bad working  code (inside spiders directory)

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from cinefil.items import Article
#from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor  ==> depreciated

from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy import log

class CinefilSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name="cinefil"
    allowed_domains = ["allocine.fr"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=29007.html"]
    rules = [

        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('(/film/)((?!:).)*$'),), callback="parse_item", follow=False)
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        ROOTPATH = '//div[@class="meta-body-item"]'
        item = Article()

        casiers = response.xpath(ROOTPATH).extract()        

        for matos in casiers:

            print("\n-----      ------       ------        --------         ---------")

            print(matos)


        return item
```

Comment: You should create xpath for each field of item

Comment: i am unable  to catch deeper than div "meta-body-item", i had crash on my test due to syntax error while writting xpath to each                                       my items.py is like this                                                                                                                          from scrapy import Item, Field


class Article(Item):
    date = Field()
    director = Field()
    actor = Field()
    genre = Field()
    country = Field()

Comment: Could you tell the movie's,director's,actors' name as it is in the website? Since different language, having trouble getting exactly which tag you want parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For extracting the movie's,director's,actors' name on the page [allocine.fr](http://www.allocine.fr/film/fichefilm_gen_cfilm=29007.html)

---

**Movie name**

```
#get from <div class="titlebar-title titlebar-title-lg">
>>> movie=response.xpath('//div[@class="titlebar-title titlebar-title-lg"]/text()').extract_first()
>>> movie
u'Spider-Man'
```

---

**Director name**

```
#start from 
#<span itemprop="director">
#<a>
#<span itemprop="name">
>>> director=response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="director"]/a/span[@itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
>>> director
u'Sam Raimi'
```

---

**Actors name**

```
#Take the word "Avec" as landmark and get its siblings <spans>
>>> movie_stars=response.xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Avec")]/following-sibling::span/text()').extract()
>>> movie_stars
[u'Tobey Maguire', u'Willem Dafoe', u'Kirsten Dunst', u' plus ']

#remove last item 'plus'
>>> movie_stars.pop()
u' plus '
>>> movie_stars
[u'Tobey Maguire', u'Willem Dafoe', u'Kirsten Dunst']
```

---

And the **items.py** should be declared as :

```
import scrapy

class Movie(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    director = scrapy.Field()        
    actors = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: Sure, glad to help!